# Enabling offline for firebase realtime database using Ionic app with capacitor

Tags: javascript, ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using ionic with firebase realtime database and capacitor 3. I intend to enable offline capabilities. I have built the app using ionic cap build and then opened in xcode. Then following url https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities I added the below code in AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true

        return true
    }
```

Now to test i ran the app with wifi on and got the data from firebase db. after this i killed the app and turned off wifi. However, on launching the app it does not load the data.

Is there anything else i am missing here?

my key pod file has:

```
target 'App' do
  capacitor_pods
  # Add your Pods here
  pod 'FirebaseCore', '7.11.0' # Add this line
  pod 'Firebase/Database', '7.11.0' # Add this line
end
```

Below is my code that does not work and expected to:

```
getSeedConfig(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
        const doc = ref(this.db, 'config/seed');
        get(doc).then((snapshot) => {
          if (snapshot.exists()) {
            resolve(snapshot.val())
          } else {
            resolve(null)
          }
        }).catch((error) => {
          reject(error)
        });
  })
}
```

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i have added the sample code

Comment: Hmm... that looks fine at first glance, although it's quite a convoluted way to get the first element from the observable. [Calling `first()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/first) on it should do the same (iirc).

Comment: so, whats the advise here?

Comment: Well... I'd recommend to use `first()`, or even a [`get` or `once`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once) without rxjs, here. --- But in our current code, is your `subscribe` callback ever called while offline?

Comment: so i have modified the code not yes tested offline as i am not sure if this code looks good to you using get based on the docs?

Answer (score 1):

When using a modern API in JavaScript there are not many cases where you need to return a custom promise anymore.

As far as I can tell this code that you now have:

```
getSeedConfig(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
        const doc = ref(this.db, 'config/seed');
        get(doc).then((snapshot) => {
          if (snapshot.exists()) {
            resolve(snapshot.val())
          } else {
            resolve(null)
          }
        }).catch((error) => {
          reject(error)
        });
  })
}
```

Can be shortened to:

```
getSeedConfig(){
  const doc = ref(this.db, 'config/seed');
  return get(doc).then((snapshot) => {
    return snapshot.val(); //  returns null when the snapshot does not exist
  })
}
```

Comment: Well two points: i am using hybrid framework ionic so not truly web. 2nd I am using promise as i need to wait for that code to return me the config data before i can take the next steps based on values. So, by shortning code, a call to getSeedConfig() will no longer wait and won't give me desirable consistent results. Please share your thought

Comment: This code returns a promise with the result, the exact same as your original code does. Did you try it?

Comment: I did not. And yes tried now and it works very much like my older promise code. This is much shorter and cleaner.  As i understood for ionic like case i would need to explicitly set Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true in the swift version. This is not automatic like for firestore documents db case. Correct?

Comment: The native SDKs for iOS and Android automatically enable the local cache, while the JavaScript SDK does not. I don't fully get how the Swift and JavaScript code in your question are related to each other, but that might just be my lack of (recent) experience with Ionic.

Comment: I might be confused as well. Let me say what i understand and it might bring some conclusions. In recent times, ionic has ditched cordova over capacitor framework. So, as a result now ionic build results into a xcode and android native projects. Now, i have no idea if it means i need to manually put the code to enable persistence in AppDelegate.swift or i assume it will be taken care.

Comment: Just to add, I gave it a try by switching off the network and it seems getSeedConfig does not work and i dont get data from offline cache etc.